# Making two images of equal dimensions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i am trying to apply SURF algorithm, which is the algo to find the key points and matches corresponding two images, but the problem is that in my case , i want to apply that algo with two images, but they are of different dimension and so it fails to work, could you please tell what shall i do so that both images become equal dimensions.

Comment: Matlab is pretty well documented.  What have you learnt from the documentation so far, and what have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your problem. If the images have the same resolution, I suggest you either crop one image or extend one image (with zeros?) to match the number of pixels.

Otherwise I suggest you interpolate the images so that they are defined at the same points, for example with [interp2](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/interp2.html).

Can you give a minimum working code example of what you are trying to do?

Edit:

The [code example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300) you gave starts with loading to images.

```
% Example 2, Corresponding points
% Load images
I1=imread('TestImages/lena1.png');
I2=imread('TestImages/testc2.png');
```

Here are a few examples of how you can make the images match. You have to decide which one of these makes sense in your case.

Method 1: crop both images

```
nrows = min(size(I1,1), size(I2,1));
ncols = min(size(I1,2), size(I2,2));

% The + floor( ... ) is only for centering the bounding box
croppedI1 = I1( (1:nrows) + floor((size(I1,1)-nrows)/2), ...
  (1:ncols)+floor((size(I1,2)-ncols)/2), ...
  :);

croppedI2 = I2( (1:nrows) + floor((size(I2,1)-nrows)/2, ...
  (1:ncols) + floor((size(I2,2)-ncols)/2), ...
  :);

I1=croppedI1;
I2=croppedI2;
```

Method 2: Extend the images with zeros until they match

```
nrows = max(size(I1,1), size(I2,1));
ncols = max(size(I1,2), size(I2,2));
nchannels = size(I1,3);

extendedI1 = [ I1, zeros(size(I1,1), ncols-size(I1,2), nchannels); ...
  zeros(nrows-size(I1,1), ncols, nchannels)];

extendedI2 = [ I2, zeros(size(I2,1), ncols-size(I2,2), nchannels); ...
  zeros(nrows-size(I2,1), ncols, nchannels)];

I1=extendedI1;
I2=extendedI2;
```

Method 3: Scale the second image to the size of the first one (which destroys the aspect ratio)

```
% Scale the coordinates so that they range from 0 to 1 each.
[X1, Y1]=meshgrid( linspace(0, 1, size(I1,2)), linspace(0, 1, size(I1,1)));
[X2, Y2]=meshgrid( linspace(0, 1, size(I2,2)), linspace(0, 1, size(I2,1)));
nchannels = size(I1,3);

% interpolate each color plane separately
for k=1:nchannels
  scaledI2(:,:,k)=interp2(X2, Y2, double(I2(:,:,k)), X1, Y1); 
end

%I1=I1;
I2=scaledI2;
```

Comment: actually i am trying to implement the code on the following website [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300) but this works only when two images given have the same dimensions , i want to make this code work where one image has some dimension and other has some other dimension, if i do this with current code, it gives the error                                               ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> example2 at 27
  I(:,1:size(I1,2),:)=I1; I(:,size(I1,2)+1:size(I1,2)+size(I2,2),:)=I2;
can you resolve this for me?

Answer (score 0):

```
% code for to play the images or to take same size images into array

r=0;c=0;

a1=imread(filename1);    

[r c]=size(a1);

b=imread(filename2);

a2= imresize(b, [r c/3]); 

% re-sized second image according to 1st one if u have specific   
 row col number then you can give like that 

a=cat(4,a1,a2);       % "a" array having a1 a2 images       

implay(a,framerate );   % to play images
```